# UICollectionView Footer not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am trying show footer on collection view. In my story board i set accessory as footer in UICollectionView and i took collection reusable view.

```
[self.cv registerClass:[ItemFooterView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView"];//in view did load

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemFooterView *footerView=[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return footerView;

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    }
```

still footer not showing if any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(300, 60);
```

make sure you have set the size for the footer

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to register `class/nib` for the footer view. Do this in `viewDidLoad`

```
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[FooterView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView"];
```

Comment: I have registerClass as well in view did load. I modified my question.

Comment: What happens if you write [footerView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]]; in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind before returning it ?